# Is "I hadn't read it yet" correct?

Tags: grammar

Context: See this [tweet](https://twitter.com/sonamakapoor/status/1280764585381855232?s=19).

Is "I hadn't read it yet" correct in the above context? It would be better if you bolster your claims with a credible source.

Comment: I think you need to clarify why you think the sentence is wrong, because so far all answers focus on the verb tense but your comments on my answer seem to indicate you have doubts about the use of _yet_ - even if none of the three people that answered saw any problem with that. That seems to indicate that what you seem to think is an obvious problem with the sentence is actually _not_ the obvious problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems totally fine.

Someone sent her something that she *had not read yet*. The past perfect refers to the time before that person sent her that text. The sending happened in the past, and the "
not having read it" was before that.

If she would have tweeted, as @AkshayPrasath proposes, "Thanks for this.. I **haven’t** read it yet..", it would mean that she thanks someone for sending her something, but she hasn't found the time yet to read it.

That *could* be a reasonable thing to say, if someone had given you a book: "Thank you for the book you gave me. Unfortunately, I haven't read it yet."

Comment: Is "yet" fine in "I hadn't read it yet"?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it be? Before she was sent the article, she had not read it yet - implying that now, she has read it.

Comment: But "yet" is for the present and future, isn't it?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, I am not aware of such a "rule". Yes, it can be used in the future, but sentences like "We'll make a man of you yet" are rather uncommon (and actually a source of questions on this site).

Comment: How can you use it in the past?

Comment: Like in that tweet? Or Chapka's answer to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54166/meaning-of-yet-with-past-simple). Or "When I entered the room, I saw it hadn't been cleaned yet". (Which has a different meaning from "When I entered the room, I saw it hadn't been cleaned"! The first means it would be cleaned at some point, I just entered the room "too early", whereas the second version implies that someone had forgotten or refused to clean the room).

Comment: See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/yet. See the warning: We don’t use yet to refer to something that has happened.

Comment: Yes, that warning is about things that _happened_, not saying you cannot use the past tense. Simply look at the example. In my examples, it's about things that had _not_ happened (yet) at some past moment , even if they may have happened in the present. The dictionary simply warns against a common mistake where people confuse _yet_ and _already_.

Comment: *"Yes, that warning is about things that happened, not saying you cannot use the past tense."* — What's the difference between *"things that happened"* and *"past tense"*?

Comment: Past tense does not mean something actually happened: "The car did not crash". If I say "The car did not crash yet", I imply it _will_ crash at some later point in time.

Comment: Ohhh!! Great example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means "at that point in the past, I had not yet read it. However I may have read it since then. "

Answer (score -1):

It is incorrect.

The correct usage would be "I haven't read it yet"

I hadn't read is past perfect tense which points to an event in the past. It is used to make it clear that one event happened before another in the past

Comment: It _does_ correctly refer to another past event, namely the fact that someone sent her something.